# Chi squared in R - testing for differences from one column

Tags: r, count, statistics, chi-squared

I'm fairly new to R so having a few teething problems.  I've created a count table, which shows counts of two groups (members and non-members) for different categories:

```
countbenefits <- table(perceptions$VOI.member, perceptions$Advantages)
countbenefits

    Community/\nteamwork Don't know Environment Future Generations None Other Personal benefits Village benefits
  Member                        6         15          31                  4   49     4                22                2
  Non-member                    0         51          10                  2   11     0                10                0
```

What I'd like to do is test for significant differences in each category between members and non-members, so for example is there a significant difference between members and non-members for Environment.  I think that I'm best using chi-squared for this, but can't work out in R how to do this from this table.

Just using the chisquared function tests between all of the categories which isn't what I want to do.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation of `chisq.test`: If you supply a two-dimensional object (like your table) to `chisq.test` then the chi-square test of independece is used (as you noticed). As this tests wether or not two random variables are independent it is not meaningful for one category where we have only one RV (number of members/non-members) left.

If you are looking only at one category at a time, you can only test if the number of members/non-members follows a specific distribution. In your case this will probalby be a binomial distribution (you have two outcomes). So I suggest you use `binom.test`.

However it is also possible to use the goodness-of-fit variant of the chi-squared test. For this you supply only the table-column in question together with the `p` argument to `chisq.test`. Note however that you will get only approximate results (as always with chi-squared). The binomial test I mentioned before will give you exact p-values.